# Creating restify createJsonClient

Tags: node.js, restify

Trying to write some mocha tests for my restify server.  Some of the services require an Authorization header.

I am trying to set it this way:

```
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
  version: '1.0.0',
  url: 'http://localhost:9000',
  headers: {Authorization:'Bearer ' + global.access_token}

});
```

but inspecting the request headers shows its not getting set, and my test is failing because of invalid credentials.

reading here, i believe i have the headers option.

http://restifyjs.com/#jsonclient

global.access_token is being set correctly.

Can someone help with some options on how to set that header?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The header was getting set.  there was a _headers node higher up in the stack and i could see that the Authorization header was getting set, but as the value:

```
'Bearer undefined'
```

So for some reason when the restify client was getting created it can not get the value from global, although its getting set in my test 01-test.
In the body of the 02-test, i can console the value and see it.
So either.

1. The value isn't set by the time the next test starts.
2. The value can't be retrieved in the restify client setup

Either way, I solved it by actually writing the token synchronously to a tmp file and reading it subsequent tests.  Seems hacky, but maybe something else will come to mind.